# Reading new Type using Hibernate from Informix

Tags: java, hibernate, informix

I have defined a column in an Informix database with the new undocumented type *longlvarchar*. Using JDBC I can read this column by getting the binary stream , but I could not find way to read this column using hibernate. I have defined a class which implements InformixDialect and I have registered this clas so hibernate can use it. In this class I tried to map the type **Longlvarchar** to **longvarchar** (and other types), but there is no way to read the data. 
Using the dao like: `testDao.findTestList().get(0).getLlvarchar()` prints only 
*com.informix.jdbc.IfxUDT@2c708440*. How can I register this new type to hibernate, or read it as binarystream just like JDBC? I am using hibernate 5.2.12 final.

**JDBC:**

```
private void getMetainf() {
    try (Statement stmt = con.createStatement(); ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery("select * from verylongvarchar where id = 1");) {
        ResultSetMetaData rsmd = res.getMetaData();
        System.out.println(con.getMetaData());

        res.next();
        readStream(res.getBinaryStream(2));


    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("Select Failed ...\n" + e.getMessage());
        logger.error(" Get failed ", e);

    }
}

private void readStream(final ResultSet res) {
    try {
        InputStream in = res.getBinaryStream(2);

        byte[] temp = new byte[100];
        int i = -1;
        while ((i = in.read(temp)) != -1) {

            // Create String from bytes
            String s = new String(temp, 0, i);
            System.out.println(s);
        }
        in.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**Hibernate:**
Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "verylongvarchar")

public class TestEntity extends QidbEntity implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 6249297171036357454L;

@Id
@Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
private Integer id;

@Column(name = "llvarchar", columnDefinition = "longlvarchar")

private String llvarchar;

@Column(name = "longvarchar")
private String longvarchar;

@Column(name = "textcolumn")
private String textcolumn;

@Column(name = "normaltext")
private String normaltext;
...
```

My Dao:

```
public class TestDao extends AbstractDAO {

public List<TestEntity> findTestList() {
    return findEntities(TestEntity.class);
}

public TestEntity findResult() {
    String query = "SELECT te FROM TestEntity te where te.id = 1";
    return createQuery(query, TestEntity.class).getSingleResult();
}
```

}
overriding Informixdialect:

```
public class InformixDataType extends InformixDialect {

public InformixDataType() {
    super();

    registerColumnType(Types.LONGVARCHAR, "longlvarchar");
    registerHibernateType(Types.LONGVARCHAR, "longlvarchar");
}
}
```